# PInvoke FatalExecutionEngineError in Diffrent Thread

Tags: c#

my code is working fine, but after 5-10 minutes, I get the following error;

Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x641ad419, on thread 0x5d0c. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Called from different threads;

```
InvokeUtil.getInstance.Calculate(localVal);
```

My Code;

```
public class InvokeUntil
{
    private IntPtr m_object = IntPtr.Zero;
    private static InvokeUntil Self;

    private InvokeUntil()
    {
        this.m_object = InvokeUntil.DllCreateInstance();
    }

    [DllImport("xDll")]
    private static extern IntPtr DllCreateInstance();

    [DllImport("xDll")]
    private static extern void DllDisposeInstance(IntPtr CSObject);

    [DllImport("xDll")]
    private static extern void DllCalculate(IntPtr pCSObject, byte[] pCurrentData, uint[] pResult);


    public static InvokeUntil getInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (InvokeUntil.Self == null)
                InvokeUntil.Self = new InvokeUntil();
            return InvokeUntil.Self;
        }
    }

    public void Calculate(uint[] EffVal)
    {
        InvokeUntil.DllCalculate(m_object, Data.MyData, EffVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I would guess that this could be a concurrency issue.  I see that the DLL supports a `DllCreateInstance` method, which would seem to suggest that it maintains some kind of state.  Is the call to `DllCalculate` thread-safe in the DLL?  I would guess not

Comment: @Martin Obviously I can't see the dll content. But what you mean is that I should call? ; InvokeUtil.DllDisposeInstance (m_object);

Comment: What I mean is that the instance of `m_object` isn't thread-safe, so calling it more than once at the same time will cause a concurrency issue.

Comment: Since it is an intermittent failure usually on of two things is happening 1) It is an alignment issue.  You application is given a range of memory that is can asses in bytes.  If the compiler options aren't set to agree with the dll you may exceed the memory size by a few bytes if the alignment mode (1,2,4,8 bytes) is set properly 2) The issue is in the dll code.

Comment: Even when I run it with a single thread, the result is the same. @jdweng The dll is 64bit but I am debugging in 32bit mode so is this a problem?

Comment: You have to look at both the addressing mode and the data mode.  If the dll is 64 bit in c# you are either on a even or on an odd 32 address.  If you are send 32 bit data you should be ok.  If you are sending 64 bit data you are ok if you are on a even address but an odd address and you are on the last word of you memory space the last 32 bits would go pass your memory range and cause an exception.

Comment: DllCalculate() cannot be safely written, it has no idea how large the arrays might be.   Writing beyond the end of the array corrupts the GC heap, ultimately triggering FEEE when the garbage collector notices the damage.  Fix by adding a parameter that passes EffVal.Length so proper error checking is now possible.

Comment: I compiled my project as x64, my problem is solved thanks.